# Pandas combine multiple rows into one row with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to combine rows into single row with condition. (Language: Python, Data-frame: Pandas)
For example:

```
Current data:

        0      1        2     3    4
     0  data1
     1         string1  num1  ex1  bla1    
     2         string2
     3         string3
     4  data2  
     5         string4  num2  ex2  bla2
     6         string5

Result:

        0      1                        2     3    4 
     0  data1  string1 string2 string3  num1  ex1  bla1
     0  data2  string4 string5          num2  ex2  bla2
```

But I can not find logic to this problem. Any idea?

[image: Current Data]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use:**

```
g = df['0'].ffill()

d = df.groupby(g, sort=False).first()
d['1'] = df['1'].dropna().groupby(g).agg(' '.join)
d = d.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Details:**

Create a grouper `g` using [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) on `df['0']`:

```
print(g)
0     data1
1     data1
2     data1
3     data1
4     data2
5     data2
6     data2
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe on grouper `g` and aggregate using `first`, then use [`Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) on column `1` and use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the column `1` on `g` and aggregate using `join`, finally use `reset_index`:

```
print(d)
        0                        1     2    3         4
0   data1  string1 string2 string3  num1  ex1      bla1    
1   data2          string4 string5  num2  ex2      bla2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a choice of how to handle the other axes (other than the one being concatenated). This can be done in the following two ways:
*Take the union of them all, join='outer'. This is the default option as it results in zero information loss.
*Take the intersection, join='inner'.

Here is an example of each of these methods. First, the default joins ='outer' behaviour:

```
In [8]: df4 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
   ...:                     'D': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
   ...:                     'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
   ...:                    index=[2, 3, 6, 7])
   ...: 

In [9]: result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, sort=False)
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0IqS.png)

Here is the same thing with join='inner':

```
 In [10]: result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join='inner')
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLJ4O.png)